# NHibernate : How to add a criteria on "ROWID" (SQLite special column)

Tags: sqlite, nhibernate

I have a view on an SQLite table that I create using NHibernate Criteria. Now I want to get the position of one specific row inside the view, of which I happen to know the Id.

Since I am using GUIDs as primary key I refer to ROWID column, which every SQLite table has.

The SQL should look like this (tested and works fine in SQLite):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Supplier
WHERE ROWID < (SELECT ROWID FROM Supplier WHERE Id = 'e3a279f6-6761-44a8-b037-f4ea82e9595f') 
AND [view restrictions]
```

Now I want to make a NHibernate query that does the same using Criteria:

```
Guid id = Guid.Parse("e3a279f6-6761-44a8-b037-f4ea82e9595f")
var rowidSubQuery = DetachedCriteria.For<Supplier>()
    [.. flexible view criteria here ..]
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Id", id))
    .SetProjection(Projections.SqlProjection(
        "ROWID as row", new[] { "row" }, new IType[] { NHibernateUtil.String }));

int pos = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Supplier))
    .Add(Restrictions.Lt("ROWID", rowid))
    .SetProjection(Projections.RowCount())
    .UniqueResult<int>();
```

But it fails with a QueryException "could not resolve property: ROWID of: Supplier". I understand that I don't have a property Supplier.ROWID, but ROWID is a valid column in SQLite. How can I still access it?

The DetachedCriteria itself works. The problem seems to be in the line

```
.Add(Restrictions.Lt("ROWID", rowid))
```

Comment: The solution, I mean THE solution, would be to map any column which is in table to some property of your entity. Then you can use it "natural" NHibernate way. There are options how to use not mapped columns *(with some SQL projections and restrictions...)* But it does not make any sense. In extreme, it could be at least *protected* property *(not available to upper layers)* but available for queries ... for filtering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Radim, that actually worked! I added a new property in my class and a mapping for it. Hadn't thought so, but it is mapped nicely and I can use it in queries. The only drawback I see is that I have to load an extra 4 bytes for each item.

```
public class Supplier 
{
    ...
    public virtual int RowId { get; protected set; }
}

public class SupplierMap : ClassMap<Supplier>
{
    ...
    Map(x => x.RowId).ReadOnly();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for trying it. Great to see you made it!